# Magento 2 : Empty html tag in theme

Tags: magento2, theme, html

I am working in the home page on the theme and it generates empty `strong` tags
[image]

How can I find and remove it

Any helps? Thank in advance.

Comment: In subline editor open your project. ctrl + shift + f and find figcaption word. Now find in result.

Comment: Thank for your reply, my problem is solved.